# Jython - SyntaxError: 'with' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6

Tags: java, jython

I am trying to import the `requests` package using `jython-compile-maven-plugin` but I get `SyntaxError: 'with' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6` in the `setup.py` which I will not be able to change. What can I do to resolve this?

I am using Jython 2.5.3.

Comment: I have this exact same problem - though I'm using Jython 2.7-b2

Comment: Looks like the issue is here: http://sourceforge.net/p/mavenjython/code/ci/master/tree/jython-compile-maven-plugin/src/main/resources/net/sf/mavenjython/ and here http://sourceforge.net/p/mavenjython/code/ci/master/tree/jython-compile-maven-plugin/src/main/java/net/sf/mavenjython/JythonMojo.java#l52 These lines need upgrading to a more recent version

Answer (score 0):

jython is too old to support the new python feature.
You can use the urllib2 module instead because urllib2 is python's own module, and jython is ok for urllib2.
Or, you can use the requests 0.9.3 version. That version is ok for jython.
Thanks.